# Informatica Data Quality Developer Tool Parameter file

Tags: informatica

My project migrated from Power Center to IDQ developer and I had to move all my mappings to IDQ developer. I was able to migrate everything except for the parameter files.

It seems that the layout and syntax for parameter file is different from Power Center. Is there anyone who can supply a sample of a parameter file for IDQ? As well as a sample shell script to run the mapping or application from the Command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the mapping and go to the parameters section and click on export parameter. This will create a parameter file in the location specified.

[image]

Running the workflow from command line

> infacmd wfs startWorkflow -dn DomainName -sn ServiceName -un UserName
>   -pd Password -a AppName -wf WorkflowName -pf ParamFile -w true